# Cassandra node down...any ideas why?

Tags: cassandra

I've put up a test cluster - four nodes. Severely underpowered(!) - ok CPU, only 2 gigs of ram, shared non ssd storage. Hey, it's test :)

I just kept it running for three days. No data going in or out..everything's just idle. Connected with opscenter.

This morning, we found one of the nodes went down around 2 am last night. The OS didn't go down (was responding to pings). The cassandra log around that time is:

```
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:114] 2014-07-29 02:07:34,952 Memtable.java:360 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-107-Data.db (686 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1406304454537, position=29042136)
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-07-29 02:08:24,227 GCInspector.java:116 - GC for ParNew: 276 ms for 1 collections, 648591696 used; max is 1040187392
```

Next entry is:

```
INFO  [main] 2014-07-29 09:18:41,661 CassandraDaemon.java:102 - Hostname: xxxxx
```

i.e. when we restarted the node through opscenter.

Does that mean it crashed on GC, or that GC finished and something else crashed? Is there some other log I should be looking at?

Note: In opscenter eventlog, we see this:

```
7/29/2014, 2:15am   Warning Node reported as being down: xxxxxxx
```

I appreciate the nodes are underpowered, but for being completely idle, it shouldn't crash, should it?

Using 2.1.0-rc4 btw.

Comment: What is your `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` set to?  With only 2GB of RAM, maybe you could try lowering it.  It would run GC more often, but it would have a better chance of completing.

Comment: That might be why. I'm letting it figure it out with env.sh. It's around 990-ish that it's allocated to heap. Is there any log entry I can look for to confirm it's the heap?

Comment: If it's the heap, it should have created a dump file in `cassandra/bin`.  Either way, check through the heap tuning doc just to be sure: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is your node was shut down by the OOM killer. Because the Linux system over commits ram, when a heavy stress is on the system it may shut down applications to recover memory for the os. With 2G total ram this can happen very easily.

Comment: That seems very likely....is there a log entry generated somewhere when that happens?

Comment: The kernel is in charge of that so you should se an entry in your syslog.

Comment: Thanks. I have to fill a few more characters for the comment, so... :)

Comment: how can i bring node up from down